# Prevent users from accessing files using non apache-rewritten urls

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, security

May be a noob question but I'm just starting playing around with apache and have not found a precise answer yet.

I am setting up a web app using url-rewriting massively, to show nice urls like [mywebsite.com/product/x] instead of [mywebsite.com/app/controllers/product.php?id=x].

However, I can still access the required page by typing the url [mywebsite.com/app/controllers/product.php?id=x]. I'd like to make it not possible, ie. redirect people to an error page if they do so, and allow them to access this page with the "rewritten" syntax only.

What would be the easiest way to do that? And do you think it is a necessary measure to secure an app?

Comment: You should update your question title. It is misleading.

Comment: Why would it be more secure? Why do you want to prevent the user from using the 'ugly' method?

Comment: Why is it insecure that `/app/controllers/product.php?id=x` is still possible?

Comment: Just the first idea I had, assuming that the less people know about the way your app is organized, the lower the risk for them to hack into it.

Comment: Btw, I'm just getting into how to secure web apps so would be awesome if you had some good resource about it to share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REDIRECT_URL} ! ^/app/controllers/product.php$
RewriteRule ^app/controllers/product.php$ /product/x [R,L]

RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ /app/controllers/product.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The first rule will redirect any request to `/app/controllers/product.php` with no `REDIRECT_URL` variable set to the clean url. The Rewrite (last rule) will set this variable when calling the real page and won't be redirected.

Answer (score 2):

In your PHP file, examine the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and ensure it is being accessed the way you want it to be.

There is no reason why this should be a security issue.